# Easiest way to convert a NSString to its currency equivalent in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I have a NSString value of @"78000". How do I get this in currency format, i.e. $78,000 with it remaining an NSString.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use a number formatter. Note this is also how you would display dates/times etc in the correct format for the users locale

```
// alloc formatter
NSNumberFormatter *currencyStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

// set options.
[currencyStyle setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSNumber *amount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:78000];

// get formatted string
NSString* formatted = [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:amount]

[currencyStyle release];
```

Answer (score 3):

The decimal/cents at the end can be controlled as follows:

```
[currencyStyle setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
```

Here's the documentation link from [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMaximumFractionDigits%3a)

Answer (score 3):

The answer above will convert a number but here is a method for actually converting a NSString to currency format

```
- (NSString*) formatCurrencyWithString: (NSString *) string
{
    // alloc formatter
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    // set options.
    [currencyStyle setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];

    // reset style to no style for converting string to number.
    [currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

    //create number from string
    NSNumber * balance = [currencyStyle numberFromString:string];

    //now set to currency format
    [currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    // get formatted string
    NSString* formatted = [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:balance];

    //release
    [currencyStyle release];

    //return formatted string
    return formatted;
}
```