# Adding a comma to currency in pay day app

Tags: ios, xcode, currency

Having looked at other posts, unfortunately I still do not understand what to change when people mention the [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) code in order to add commas to currency strings in my payday app.  I'm very new to this, and my current code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)calculateButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender

    {
        float dailyRate = [self.dailyRateTextField.text floatValue];
        float daysWorked = [self.daysWorkedTextField.text floatValue];
        float grossPay = dailyRate * daysWorked;
        float taxRate = .72;
        float ssRate = .938;
        float medRate = .9855;
        float nillRate = 1;

        if (medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) medRate = medRate;
        else medRate = nillRate;

        if (ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on) ssRate = ssRate;
        else ssRate = nillRate;

        if (fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) taxRate = taxRate;
        else taxRate = nillRate;

        float netPay = grossPay * taxRate * medRate * ssRate;
        self.dailyRateTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", dailyRate];
        self.netIncomeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", netPay];
        self.grossIncomeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", grossPay];

        }
```

**I just need to implement a comma in the netIncomeTextField and grossIncomeTextField.**  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an iOS expert, but it seems that what other people may have been trying to say is that you create an [NSNumberFormatter object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-9197) and call `NSNumberFormatter::setHasThousandSeparators( true)`, and run all your currency values through that.

I also believe that [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544314/easiest-way-to-convert-a-nsstring-to-its-currency-equivalent-in-cocoa) should assist you